# Proxy server at home, for web application access

Tags: windows-7, networking, proxy

I have an application on the internet that requests a proxy to access.

I could buy one and put it there, the format he asks for is the following:

```
http: // ip: port OR http: // username: password @ ip: port
```

But I would like to create my own, from the computer of my house.

I am a layman to get to the point of creating mine without seeing a step by step.

Maybe it involves no-ip, and some application installed on my computer. I have no idea how to start.

**In short:**
I have an application that does the management of Instagram (NextPost). It says to use Proxy from the same country that the account was created (in this case, Brazil) .. I would like to use my computer as a proxy for my web application.

Can someone help-me? Thanks.

Comment: Your question isn’t clear to me. What does your first line mean? Can you post the application name and the exact text where it requests the proxy? What does it need a proxy for?

Comment: @Steve I have an application that does the management of Instagram (NextPost). It says to use Proxy from the same country that the account was created (in this case, Brazil) .. I would like to use my computer as a proxy for my web application.

Comment: I could buy some proxy in Brazil, but I would like to do the same.

Comment: You describe an app demanding a proxy in Brazil. I hope you are in Brazil, otherwise your newly created proxy on your computer will not meet this condition. And, since I'm slightly puzzled by this request for such a proxy from this app, could it be that this is requested because you are _not_ in Brazil? In which case you would be better off with a VPN proxy.

Comment: @reben I'm in Brazil, about the application runs on a server hired, which stays in the United States. the Application makes access to Instagram, so it does access from the United States, right? However, if it is recommended that the accesses be made in Brazil, that is, it is recommended that you use Proxy. Can I create my own proxy instead of buying?

Comment: If the application demands a proxy from Brazil then yes you can make a proxy from Brazil, only dependant on how the location is determined. But I have this suspicion that some info _may_ be missing here.. http ip:port or username:password does not imply any proxy. Does not deny it either, but..

Comment: If you want, give Instagram management system access to test yourself. The goal is to follow people, automatically comment, and everything. The proxy formats they accept are the same as the one you comment on. Alias, I just bought some and put it there. I would like to create my proxy and not get buying. After all, I live in Brazil, my IP is from Brazil, I would just like to put an access point here for the application to work. @reben thanks for attention.

Comment: You can see here: https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/images/001/670/414/full/agelessbroficial_-_Mozilla_Firefox.jpg?1539624602

Comment: OK, thanks for the info. When you specify a proxy you give it in the format of host:ip or username: etc. I don't know if it matters here, but I also read the following out of this; It recommends a proxy but it's not mandatory. It does not seem to need this access point. You can set up a proxy on your own machine if you want, but doing so _may_ defeat it's own purpose (depending on what it is) since the proxy will most likely have the same external IP as your browser/machine. If you want to access that proxy from the internet you may have to deal with the possibility of your IP not being fixed.

Comment: @reben , Yes, I do not care about Proxy the same IP as my machine. In fact, for me this is the ideal scenario. In IP being dynamic, I think the program (no-ip) could fix this, since its role is to synchronize every 5 minutes my IP from now with a domain name (hostname). The question is, how do I do this? I'm a layman, I need a tutorial starting this part for me. Can I find something about what I want to do?

Comment: I maxed out on my previous comment with 0 chars to go. Now that I believe I understand more of what you are looking for I'll make an answer to your question. If this is the answer you're looking for then accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not stating what computer you have to run the proxy server on, and there are many proxy servers available. One easy choice would be Squid, which is available for both Linux and Windows. I'm somewhat uncertain as to what level to inform on here but;

- You will find Squid at http://www.squid-cache.org/
- Download (preferably) a binary package from http://www.squid-cache.org/Versions/
- You'll find the Docs at http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/

Innstallation samples are many on the web, both for Linux flavors and Windows.
I do not see the benefit of cutting & pasting any documentation here.

EDIT: I still do not know what OS you will be running on, but if you choose to go with squid, it does not seem to have uPnP for NAT Traversal, so you may want to look up how to add a NAT rule for your home network router.

This to enable incoming connections to your proxy from the internet. It is a common area to fail in.

Usually this is quite simple. Let's assume that your PC is in network 192.168.1.0 (or it could be 10.0.0.0 ..) with address 192.168.1.10, and your squid proxy runs at port 8080. The NAT rule you set up is usually in the form of;

- WAN (Internet) Port from/to port: 8080/8080
- LAN (Home Network) Port from/to port: 8080/8080
- LAN IP: 192168.1.10

Other semantics may be used, depending in the router, like source (for WAN) and destination (for LAN)(for inbound traffic).